# about maxima of function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

[image]

I know that for option (b) for $x=0.75$ maximum value is $0$ lies in interval $(0,1)$ , but answer (a) and (d) clearly not the correct but for option (b) I don't know how to proceed ; I calculate derivative but first derivative is $0$ only for $x=1$ someone please help about it? Since answer key gives answer (b) and (c) as correct option.

Comment: Except b none of the functions attain their maximum value.

Comment: thanks  for confirmation @kingW3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a method of determining extrema and the nature about them from the first derivative. Find points of $f$ where $f'(x)=0$, then check $f$ at points nearby, say $f(x+\varepsilon),f(x-\varepsilon)$ for $\varepsilon$ small and $x$ the root of the derivative.

- If both $f(x+\varepsilon),f(x-\varepsilon)>0$, then $f(x)$ is a minimum.
- If both $f(x+\varepsilon),f(x-\varepsilon)<0$, then $f(x)$ is a maximum.
- If one is positive and one is negative, $f(x)$ is a "saddle point" (neither maximum nor minimum). To clarify, think of $f(x)=x^3$, which has $f'(0)=0$.

---

For your given function (b) in particular, you can use the property that the vertex of a parabola is either the maximum or minimum globally, for leading coefficient positive and negative respectively.

To see if (c) is also valid, note that we would have

$$f'(x) = \frac \pi 2 \cos \left( \frac \pi 2 x \right)$$

This is $0$ whenever the argument of the cosine function is an odd multiple of $\pi/2$, i.e. $x = \pm 1,\pm 3, \pm 5, ...$. But none of these $x$ values are in $(0,1)$ (the open interval), so I guess (c) being correct is a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the main confusion points are $(b)$ and $(c)$.

You mentioned that the maximum value is attained when $x=0.75$, that is correct. No derivative is needed. But just for the purpose of learning, let me compute its derivative. $g'(x) = -2(x-0.75)$ and we can see that the derivative only takes value $0$ when $x=0.75$.

For part $(c)$, $\sin \left( \frac{\pi x}2\right)$ is an increasing function from $0$ to $1$ and it doesn't attain a maximum value. Its supremum is $1$.

The only correct option is indeed $(b)$.